# If $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $L^2(0,T;L^2)$ and $u_n$ bounded in $L^\infty(0,T;L^2)$, does $u_n(t) \rightharpoonup u(t)$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ a.e. $t$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $u_n$ converge weakly to $u$ in $L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ and let $u_n$ be bounded in $L^\infty(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$.

Is it true that $u_n(t) \rightharpoonup u(t)$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ (weakly) for a.a. $t$?

**It is** true that $u_n(t) \rightharpoonup v(t)$ for some $v(t) \in L^2(\Omega)$, but I don't know how to identify.

Comment: What result are you using to extract the existence of $v$ in your last statement? Is it the property of weak star compactness of the unit ball (in the dual of a separable space)?

Comment: @Pedro Since $u_n$ is bounded uniformly in $L^\infty(0,T;L^2)$, it means $\lVert u_n(t) \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}$ is bounded uniformly independent of $n$ and $t$, and every bounded sequence in a Hilbert space has a weakly convergent subsequence. Right?